# KVM guest broken after taking snapshot

Tags: kvm-virtualization

I needed to do some work on a KVM guest. To be able to go back to it's previous state, I took a snapshot:

```
virsh snapshot-create vph-share
```

After this, I tried to SSH into the VM:

```
ssh vph-share.hexvm
```

But I got

> ssh: connect to host vph-share.hexvm port 22: No route to host

This worked fine before I took the snapshot.

I took a look at the snapshot-list, it looked normal. 
I then tried to log in again, and got

> ssh: connect to host vph-share.hexvm port 22: Connection timed out

I also tried a `virsh shutdown`, but although virsh reports that the VM is being shutdown in reality it isn't. A following `virsh start` says that the VM is already active.

I tried `virsh reboot` and got:

```
error: Failed to reboot domain vph-share
error: Requested operation is not valid: Reboot is not supported without the JSON monitor
```

I tried the same actions on another VM on my server, without problems.

The log (/var/log/libvirt/qemu/vph-share.log) only has a note about the shutdown attempt:

> 2015-03-19 09:14:43.445+0000: shutting down

How can I get this VM back to work again?

The OS of the host machine is Ubuntu Server 12.04.
The OS of the KVM guest is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that, unlike the other VM's, this VM's image was owned by root:root.

I tried to `chown` it to libvirt-qemu:kvm like the other VM's, but the ownership changed back to root:root automatically.

However, this did cause the VM to be in "shut off" state. 
Starting it with `sudo virsh start vph-share` brought it back to life.